# Conditional import in React.js

Tags: reactjs, import

I need to import with condition. I am using below code and getting error.

```
if (window.location.hostname == 'sellbutton') {
  import serviceToUSe from '../public/service/sellbutton.com.json';
} else {
  import serviceToUSe from '../public/service/default.json';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to first declare an empty place to conditionally store the data after using `require` instead of importing:

```
//This might an object {} or array [] depending on your json data structure. 
var serviceToUSe = {};

if (window.location.hostname == 'sellbutton') {
  serviceToUSe = require('../public/service/sellbutton.com.json');
} else {
  serviceToUSe = require('../public/service/default.json');
}
```